# Как сделать половину слова жирной, а другую тонкой?

Tags: html, css, шрифты

В общем, суть проблемы такова: нужно сделать две половины слова с разными весами шрифта. Одна bold, другая light.
Как это грамотнее сделать? Через html/css или svg прилепить?

Должно быть что-то вроде такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: обернуть части в элементы span который задать нужные стили

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью html:

```html
<b>Кот</b>собака
```

С помощью css:

```css
p {
  font-weight: normal;
}

p span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Кот</span>собака
</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Например так `p>span`:

```css
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

p span {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Кот</span>собака
</p>
```